# Cron is not running in NestJs

Tags: node.js, cron, nestjs

I am trying to implement cron in Nest application. I am adding cron dynamically as per the documentation as I want to perform some cron operation based on POST request. So for that I have added cron dynamically using `SchedulerRegistry` but when I am making POST request cron is not running.

Below is my code:

**app.controller.ts**

```
import { Controller, Get, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

@Post('cron')
testCron(){
return this.appService.testCron();
 }
}
```

**app.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cron, Interval, SchedulerRegistry } from '@nestjs/schedule';
import { CronJob } from 'cron';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
 constructor(private schedulerRegistry:SchedulerRegistry){}

async testCron(){

  const job = new CronJob('2 * * * * *', () => {
  console.log("My cron running..."); 
});

  this.schedulerRegistry.addCronJob('sec',job);
  job.start(); 
 }
}
```

Why this cron job is not running on POST request as console statement is not showing?

Answer (score 3):

I did exactly the same you do and works. However, I cannot see how is the other parts of your code. Here is the complete code.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ScheduleModule } from '@nestjs/schedule';


@Module({
  imports: [ScheduleModule.forRoot()],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SchedulerRegistry } from '@nestjs/schedule';
import { CronJob } from 'cron';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(AppService.name);

  constructor(private schedulerRegistry: SchedulerRegistry) {}

  async testCron() {
    const job = new CronJob('2 * * * * *', () => {
      this.logger.log('My cron running...');
    });

    this.schedulerRegistry.addCronJob('sec', job);
    job.start();
  }

}
```

And here is the consult using Postman:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/cron
```

Then is printed in the console. Pay attention it's not printed each 2 second but every second 2.

```
[Nest] 15287  - 05/20/2022, 6:13:02 PM     LOG [AppService] My cron running...
[Nest] 15287  - 05/20/2022, 6:14:02 PM     LOG [AppService] My cron running...
[Nest] 15287  - 05/20/2022, 6:15:02 PM     LOG [AppService] My cron running...
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31824567)

Comment: Thank you the `ScheduleModule.forRoot()` is the solution to the problem in my case it was missing.